# How can I invoke my script from anywhere, when it has relative imports?

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path

Let's say I have a script I've written:

`~/workspace/myscript/script.py`

If I have, for example, a `~/bin` which I have added to my `$PATH`, then I could create a symbolic link

`~/bin/script  ->  ~/workspace/myscript/script.py`

And everything works fine, I can call my script from anywhere.

Then, say my script starts to grow, and I separate it out

```
~/workspace/myscript/
    script.py
    mylib.py
```

I now run into a problem, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/920842), that if I am calling my python script directly (as opposed to importing it as a module) then I cannot do a relative import.

The only solution I have seen is to package up the whole program into a fully fledged python package with a setup.py and installing it system-wide (or managing a home directory python library folder).

This seems like a lot of extra work for the sake of breaking my code into multiple python files.

Is there some way I can:

1. Call the script from anywhere (have it callable on path),
2. Have the code sparated into multiple files,
3. Not have to manage a full python package and installation.

All at once?

Comment: Why do you need relative imports for a script consisting of maybe two or three files?

Comment: If another developer checks out the files, the home path will be different, so absolute won't work.

Comment: The path of the main script is automatically added to `sys.path`. Therefore modules in the same directory can be imported absolutely.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, are you saying that it should just work as is?  Because it throws an error when I try this.

Comment: It should work with an absolute import. What is the error exactly?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named mylib`.  I have `import mylib`, is that what you mean by absolute?

Comment: Yes, this should actually work. I tried it with a Python 3.4 on Windows and a Python 2.7 on Linux and it works as expected.

Comment: You are correct this does work.  There was a bug in my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the root directory of your module to the Python path:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:~/workspace/myscript/"
```